# How to find PDF line height?

Tags: parsing, pdf, itext

In Adobe Portable Document Format Reference 1.3 one might see

```
Th → horizontal spacing

txty → move text rendering location with respect to the start of the line segment

TLM → line matrix

TM → text matrix

Tf → font

TS → text rise
```

And the `TL` operator sets the vertical difference between lines in the same paragraph. As shown by [Adobe Portable Document Format Reference Manual Version 1.3](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/PDF_1.3/PDF%20Reference%201.3.pdf), the leading is measured by the unit of line heights (like 1.2 or 1.8 times of the current line height).

From where can we find the line height itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In pdf parsing the TL operator sets the vertical difference between lines in the same paragraph. 
>   As shown by [Adobe Portable Document Format Reference Manual Version 1.3], the leading is measured 
>   by the unit of line heights (like 1.2 or 1.8 times of the current line height).
>
> From where can we find the line height itself?

- If you look at the text on the image you posted with your [cross-post in itext-general](http://itext.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-find-PDF-line-height-td4660497.html), you can read:

  [image: The leading parameter, Tl , is measured in unscaled text space units.]

  So not "unit of line heights like 1.2 or 1.8 times of the current line height" but "unscaled text space units". Thus, the TL parameter is NOT depending on some line height parameter. BTW, fairly often it is 0 because the automatic advance by Tl is quite seldomly used nowadays.

  If you need some line height nonetheless, have a look at the font size.

  Of course both leading and font size still are subject to the current transformation matrix and the text matrix...
- Why on earth are you working with such an ancient PDF reference? Since 2008 the PDF specification is an [ISO norm, 32000-1](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: Thanks! As for the "unscaled text space units", is there a way to get that? @mkl

Comment: These text space units are the units of the coordinate system you get by transforming the default user space coordinate system (usually having units of 1/72 inches) by the current transformation matrix (Cf. the **cm** operations) and the text matrix (Cf. the **Tm** operation). It is unscaled as it is not subject to the horizontal scaling or the scaling by the font size.